can't change date picker to wanted date?
I wrote a script to log in, navigate to the report page, choose dates, and download the file. However, I’m facing an issue: the date picker always returns today’s date, regardless of the format I use !!

the second issue I can't target the only the table element so I download the file
this is the HTML

for the first issue
I have used page.fill  ,page.locator with no luck
        page.fill('[id="txtFromDate"]',formatted_date)
        page.locator('[id="txtToDate"]').fill('11-08-2024')


Please share a [mcve] with the page you're automating and your full code. Thanks.

Two things you might be missing

Check if the input field in the code is editable.
Select the first element of the locator before filling

Here's a sample automation that works on a website with editable date-pickers
await page.goto('https://www.google.com/travel/flights');
await page.locator('[placeholder="Departure"]').first().fill('Fri, Aug 23');
await page.locator('[placeholder="Return"]').first().fill('Sat, Aug 24');

